# Cannot upload code to arduino

Tags: arduino, upload, port, arduino-uno

My arduino uno was working normally, but now I have some problems with uploading my new code to the board. When I plug the arduino into the computer, it only shows me port COM1. In the past, it's showed me COM3. I have installed drivers, but it still doesn't work. I tried the same thing on ubuntu and it's the same there too. When I plug it in, code that is on the arduino is working normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if no device is seen eiter in windows and linux, and/or in more computer, then possibilities are that you have fried the chip that does serial to USB conversion.
Unless you are good at SMD soldering, solution is to buy an exthernal conversion chip (USB to serial RS232-TTL 5v, pay attention as RS232 classic use 12V, and there are also TTL3V) and connect it to RX TX (pin 0 and 1), but you'll have to manually reset the board every upload; more hack (but easily possible) is needed to bring RST pin to the converter.

Answer (score 0):

Serial port name can be changed when you change Arduino IDE or the operating system that you are using on you computer. From now on your serial port which is created by Arduino is `COM1` insted of `COM3`. Thus there is no problem as far as I see.

You need to choose COM1 from your Arduino IDE  `Tools>Serial Port`.